# While compiling Qt5.9 with VC++2013 - Windows 10, getting error C2440: 'default argument': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [1]' to 'BSTR'

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, windows-10, qt5.9

I am building Qt5.9 with VC++2013, Windows 10. I am getting the error as below:

```
 C2440: 'default argument': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [1]' to 'BSTR.
```

I have read this question [error C2440: 'default argument': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [1]' to 'BSTR'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37204166/error-c2440-default-argument-cannot-convert-from-const-wchar-t-1-to-bst) but seem not my problem because I am compiling Qt5.9, not qt app project.

I found an article about this issue but it is about compiling Qt5.6 (http://wangjie.rocks/2015/12/28/compile-qt/). This is a chinese site, I need to translate using chrome. There is no file `qtbase\mkspecs\common\msvc-base.conf` in Qt5.9 but I found a similar config file `qtbase\mkspecs\common\msvc-version.conf`. I did the same but it doesn't work.

Comment: sounds like the code is bugged and your "fix" is hiding a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

It pops up error while compile `qtsystems\src\systeminfo\systeminfo.pro` so I added bellow config to that `systeminfo.pro`. It works.

```
win32: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -Zc:strictStrings
win32: QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -Zc:strictStrings
win32: QMAKE_CFLAGS -= -Zc:strictStrings
win32: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -Zc:strictStrings
```